# Algorithm to compile Lisiecki stack? (5MM-yr Temperature Record)

Tags: data

I have obtained the Lisiecki stack data from www.lorraine-lisiecki.com/stack.html

How do I convert the d18O measurement into a figure for average surface temperature? What is the best algorithm?

I found this on wikipedia: If the signal can be attributed to temperature change alone, with the effects of salinity and ice volume change ignored, a δ18O increase of 0.22% is equivalent to a 1 °C (1.8 °F) cooling.

Any help would be useful. I am also trying to find the dataset for the fabled 65-million-year temperature record.